# Limiting width of text inside a <code> block in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a website with the following setup:

```css
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
}

.containerInner {
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    margin: 0 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
}

div.body {
    margin: 0 30px 30px 30px;
}

h2 {
    color: #444444;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    padding: 10px 15px 8px 15px;
    font-family: "HelveticaLight", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
}

code {
    font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #3365A2;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    display: block;
    margin: 14px 0 14px 0;
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div id="Demo" class="containerInner">
    <h2>Demo</h2>
    <div class="body">
<pre><code>stuff {
  this is a very very very very very very very very loooooooooooooooong line of code or possibly something other than code but that still needs to be in a code tag
}</code></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem here is that lines like this in `<code>` can extend past their code box and their container, which also results in the webpage getting expanded and creating a horizontal scrollbar for the whole page, which I don't want. What I'd like is to instead (in order of preference) either:

1. have a scrollable code box (much like the ones here on SO); or
2. automatically wrap the text in some reasonable manner; or
3. simply chop off (i.e. stop displaying) the text at the end of the code box (it should still be copy-able in full, however).

How would I go around to achieving one of the 3 solutions, if possible without excessive scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `style="overflow: scroll;"` to the code block. You can alternatively add `style="overflow: auto;"`, which will only create a scroll-bar if the content overflows.

(Note: You could also add it to the CSS portion, but I made it inline just to highlight where it is.)

```css
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
}

.containerInner {
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    margin: 0 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
}

div.body {
    margin: 0 30px 30px 30px;
}

h2 {
    color: #444444;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    padding: 10px 15px 8px 15px;
    font-family: "HelveticaLight", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
}

code {
    font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #3365A2;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    display: block;
    margin: 14px 0 14px 0;
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div id="Demo" class="containerInner">
    <h2>Demo</h2>
    <div class="body">
<pre><code style="overflow: scroll;">stuff {
  this is a very very very very very very very very loooooooooooooooong line of code or possibly something other than code but that still needs to be in a code tag
}</code></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh. Well that was easier than I expected.